# How to make a webview content invisible?

Tags: android, webview, visibility

I get a video in my application from vimeo.com and I play it in a `webview`. The problem is that when I want to make that `webview`  invisible, it doesn't work. Only the container disappears but the content is still there, it is inactive(I mean you cannot control it) but it is there. It works fine with a common website, but in this case it doesn't. 
I have tried some of the WebView properties but with no result.

I'm not looking to stop,pause or resume the video in this way, I just want to make all of it invisible.

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    //mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<html><body> <iframe id='video' src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/37817858?autoplay=1&api=1'" +
            //" width='300px' height='200px' frameborder='0'></iframe></html><body> ", "text/html", "utf-8",null);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://player.vimeo.com/video/37817858");
    Button mbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    mbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mWebView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

                mWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
            else{
                mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


        }
    });
```

}

How can I do this? :)

Comment: You could try dynamically generating it when the user takes action to view it. Or possible setting the height to 0px or something. Not an Android developer, just throwing out some ideas lol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `webView.removeAllViews()` to remove all views from WebView

Comment: Yes, this removes the views, but I need to bring it back at some moment. Is this possible? I use the hidden methods `onPause` and on `onResume` of the WebView + `resume/pauseTimers()` to resume the video from where it was stopped, when I go back in the `webView's` `fragment` and I would like to recover my content. Could you tell me please, how could I do it?

Comment: Ok, I have solved in this way: `onPause()` method of the fragment I stored all the views in a View array, `View [] v`, using `webView.getChildAt(i)` then I have removed all views with `webView.removeAllViews` and then, `onResume()` method of the fragment I loaded them back, using `webView.addView(v[i])`. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` ? It works for me.

Comment: Yes, I did, It has the same effect, it works for a normal website, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think why this is happening is because when you play a video, it will have to show either a SurfaceView or a VideoView to display it (which I have had to do in the past), which will be overlaid on top of your WebView.  Fortunately they'll get added as children which is why the getChildAt()/removeAllViews()/addView() works.